# How to focus on next input box after pressing enter. jquery

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="add_address_section">

    <div class="address_field">
      <input type="text" class="add_address_field" name="field_name[]" value="">
      <input type="button" class="remove_address_button" value="Remove Address">
    </div>

    <div class="address_field">
      <input type="text" class="add_address_field" name="field_name[]" value="">
      <input type="button" class="remove_address_button" value="Remove Address">
    </div>
  </div>
```

After I click enter on an input box, I want to focus on the next input box. However, this isn't working:

```
  $('.add_address_section').on('keyup', '.address_field', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      addInputField();
      var next_inbox_index = $('.address_field').index(this) + 1;
      debugger;
      $('.address_field').eq(next_inbox_index).focus();
    }
  });
```

Anyone know why? I can't seem to get this to work:

This doesn't even seem to work:

```
$('.address_field>input')[0]
<input type=​"text" class=​"add_address_field" name=​"field_name[]​" value>​
$('.address_field>input')[0].focus()
undefined
```

and this is what this return value is:

```
$('.address_field').eq(1)
w.fn.init [div.address_field, prevObject: w.fn.init(2)]
0:div.address_field
length: 1
```

This doesn't work either:

```
$('.address_field>input[type=text]')[1]
<input type=​"text" class=​"add_address_field" name=​"field_name[]​" value>​
$('.address_field>input[type=text]')[1].focus()
undefined
```

and this doesn't even focus on the first input box:

```
$('input[type=text]')[0].focus()
undefined
```

This seems to work actually

```
$('.address_field input[type=text]')[next_inbox_index].focus()
```

Apparently while in console, this focus thing doens't work.

Comment: Can't you just copy/past the html rather than image? We can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: done, sorr about that

Comment: Does focus() just not work while in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `.address_field` is the triggering element in the delegated event listener, there's no need to keep track of the index. You can simply use the [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method to select the next `.address_field`. Then use `.find(input=text)` to select the input and set focus.

```js
$('.add_address_section').on('keyup', '.address_field', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().find('input[type=text]').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add_address_section">

  <div class="address_field">
    <input type="text" class="add_address_field" name="field_name[]" value="">
    <input type="button" class="remove_address_button" value="Remove Address">
  </div>

  <div class="address_field">
    <input type="text" class="add_address_field" name="field_name[]" value="">
    <input type="button" class="remove_address_button" value="Remove Address">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe that once you have used `eq()` to reduce the number of elements to one, you still need to use array notation to get that DOM element rather than the jquery object. so the last line should be

```
$('.address_field').eq(next_inbox_index)[0].focus();
```

Comment: `.focus()` does work for jQuery objects too! [Ref](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class **add_address_field** on the fields that you want to focus on enter

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
        <div class="add_address_section">

    <div class="address_field">
      <input type="text" class="inputs add_address_field" name="field_name[]" value="">
      <input type="button" class="remove_address_button" value="Remove Address">
    </div>

    <div class="address_field">
      <input type="text" class="inputs add_address_field" name="field_name[]" value="">
      <input type="button" class="remove_address_button" value="Remove Address">
    </div>
  </div>
            </form>

        <script>
       $('.add_address_field').keydown(function (e) {
     if (e.which === 13) {
         var index = $('.add_address_field').index(this) + 1;
         $('.add_address_field').eq(index).focus();
     }
 });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can't I just use the existing class `add_address_field`?

Comment: Neither seems to highlight the input box and my cursor still isn't in it: `$('.address_field').eq(2)[0].focus()`
undefined
`$('.address_field').eq(2).focus()`
`w.fn.init [div.address_field, prevObject: w.fn.init(4)]`

Comment: Hard refresh the page, which jquery version are you using.

Comment: 3.1.1 is my version

Comment: You might be using the class event somewhere else in the code. The above html file is working on my computer in chrome and firefox, you can also rename above to html and check it.

Comment: what do you mean class event somewhere else?

Comment: If I run this code in chrome, my cursor is supposed to appear in the input box right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164036/discussion-between-waqas-bukhary-and-jwan622).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.add_address_section').on('keyup', '.address_field', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var next_inbox_index = $('.address_field').index(this) + 1;
      $('.address_field').eq(next_inbox_index).find('.add_address_field').focus();
    }
  });
```

Plunker Link: https://plnkr.co/edit/egMb58HhvuhdDf2IjcFD

Comment: FML. This seems to work: `$('.address_field input[type=text]')[next_inbox_index].focus()`

Comment: iI updated the answer. as your way of selecting class address_field.